# C# Изменение интерфейса, используя tasks

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl

Вот у меня есть такое образное многопоточное приложение:

```
{

    for(int i = 0; i <data.Count; i++)
    {
        Task t = new Task( () => MyTask(data[i], this) );
        t.Start();
        t.Wait();

    }

    button1.Enabled = false;
    listBox1.Items.Add("Done");

}

public void MyTask(string str, Form frm1)
{

    Action action = () => { listBox1.Items.Add(str); };
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(action);
    else
        action();

}
```

То есть мне нужно запустить несколько тасков на выполнение и результаты их работы внести в листбокс. Только invoke почему-то не работает, а потом оказалось что программа виснет. Видимо из-за wait(), потому что он блокирующий. Как правильно организовать работу тасков в таком случае? (Без async/await только). И как правильно изменять контролы из тасков. Спасибо!

Comment: Эээ... Весь смысл `Task`'ов в async/await.

Comment: А так — да, у вас классический deadlock.

Comment: @VladD _"Весь смысл Task'ов в async/await"_ -- async/await есть в c#, но, например, в f# нет async/await, а Task'и используют.

Comment: @Stack: Там свои аналогичные конструкции. Если я правильно понимаю, аналогичная фича там была ещё раньше.

Comment: @Stack: http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-fsharp-async-intro.aspx/ «Asynchronous workflows in F# shipped in Visual Studio 2010 and you can use them now to write production code for a wide range of runtimes including .NET 2.0»

Comment: @VladD _"Там свои аналогичные конструкции."_ -- в c# это специальная часть языка. а в f# используются builder'ы и на их основе можно создавать свои конструкции.

Comment: @Stack: Это да, F# кажется мощнее в этом смысле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас классический deadlock.

Смотрите. Вы запускаете в другом потоке `Task` и блокируете основной поток, ожидая пока этот `Task` отработает. В это время `Task` делает `Invoke`, то есть посылает код на выполнение в основной поток, и ожидает, пока этот код отработает. Разумеется, этот код не отработает никогда, т. к. основной поток ожидает окончания `Task`'a.

Правильное, нормальное, используемое всеми решение — использовать конструкцию async/await. Ваш под при этом будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
button1.Enabled = false;
var tasks = data.Select(d => MyTask(d));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
button1.Enabled = true;
listBox1.Items.Add("Done");

// ...
public async Task MyTask(string str)
{
    // если нужна длинная обработка, то
    var result = await Task.Run(() => LongProcessing(str));
    listBox1.Items.Add(result);
}
```

---

Если вы по каким-то причинам решили остановиться в 1837 году, и не использовать технологии сегодняшнего дня, замените `Invoke` на `BeginInvoke`, тогда «хвост» задания будет выполнен позже.

Или уберите `t.Wait()`, а вместо него используйте `t.ContinueWith` (то же, что и `await`, но вручную).

Comment: Спасибо, очень все доступно. А можно такой теоретический вопрос, я так понимаю, tasks это продвинутый Thread. А как в тредах такая ситуация разрешалась, ведь там не было конструкций async/await?

Comment: Да, и если мне нужно из самого таска контрол изменить, то схема обычная? Через Invoke?

Comment: @АлександрПушкин: Не совсем. Это как бы задание, которое «прыгает» между thread'ами, и заканчивается не сразу, а когда-нибудь. Это скорее похоже на goroutine.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин: Если нужно изменить контрол из Task'а, то вы обычно просто прямо меняете этот контрол. Смотрите, в чём идея: `async Task` бежит в потоке, где его запустили, и просто «выключается» в момент ожидания на await. Если вам нужно специально перебросить выполнение в другой поток, вы делаете вложенный таск через `Task.Run`. Но основной Task будет всё время возвращаться в основной поток. Поэтому можно использовать контролы напрямую.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин: Насчёт тредов, там такие ситуации разрешались с трудом :) Обычно приходилось код основного потока разбивать на части: первая часть запускает асинхронные задания, и подписывает на завершение этих заданий вторую часть, которая и делает пост-обработку результатов.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин _"как в тредах такая ситуация разрешалась, ведь там не было конструкций async/await?"_ -- использовали Begin/End методы и IAsyncResult. см. msdn [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423(v=vs.110).aspx)